# WebSVN error when I open it

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, websvn

I followed http://agilior.pt/blogs/pedro.rainho/archive/2010/02/06/11698.aspx to install SVN and WebSVN on my laptop ( ubuntu OS ) for first time ,but when I open http://localhost/WebSVN I will get followin errors:

```
Error running this command: svn --non-interactive --config-dir /tmp log --xml --quiet 'file:////var/sourcecontrol/svn/newRepository/@' --limit 1
svn: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27)
svn: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27)
```

I google a lot to understand the problem,but I can't find anything in net about solving this.

where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

When I got the same problem appear on any `svn` command, first of all I located the lib with

`locate libxml2.so`

and found that I have three versions in `/usr/local/lib` folder:

`/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so`
`/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2`
`/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8`

so I had decided to remove `/usr/lib/libxml2.so` and `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2` and that solved a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me reinstalling libxml solved the problem. Try the following commands

```
    sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
    sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just the same problem and I resolved it including SVN bin path in config.php:

$config->setSVNCommandPath('...svn bin path...');

Cheers!